# Possible ways to call external javascript function (object) in mongo map or reduce context

Tags: javascript, mongodb, coffeescript, mapreduce

Preface:

in order to have clean and effective code, i want to use external functions in my mapreduce mongo script.

Problem:

given we have following map function (coffeescript syntax):

```
map: -> 
   key = foo(@field)
   emit(key, value)
```

Calling an external function 'foo' raise an error

```
➜ rake mongo:mapreduce
MongoDB shell version: 2.0.5
connecting to: localhost:27017/connect_development
{
    "assertion" : "map invoke failed: JS Error: ReferenceError: foo is not defined nofile_b:2",
    "assertionCode" : 9014,
    "errmsg" : "db assertion failure",
    "ok" : 0
}
```

The same we will return for reduce context call.

Bad smell decision - self-called anonymous function:

```
map: -> 
   key = ( (field)->
     # some business logic
   )(@field)

   emit(key, value)
```

Self-called anonymous function could be very big and not effective to test and may cause leaking memory (not sure on this).

How to resolve this problem?

**UPD:**

When i said "external function", meant function declared in same file (in same class) with "map/reduce" functions. Of Course, it's invoked on server-side.

Answer (score 2):

Map/reduce functions must run on the db servers, in another context, so they can't touch anything "external".

There is nothing wrong with using anonymous functions inline, they are extremely cheap - just avoid deep recursion. CoffeeScript has syntax for creating closures which you might want to use:

```
map: -> 
  key = do =>
    k = @field.doSomething()
    return k
  emit key, value
```

Answer (score 0):

Map/Reduce code executes on the MongoDB servers.  You do have the option of [storing functions server-side](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Server-side+Code+Execution#Server-sideCodeExecution-Storingfunctionsserverside) that can be called from Map/Reduce, but best practice suggests keeping functions with the rest of your code in version control.  Anonymous functions are commonly used in JavaScript and should not be an issue.